# Check if rpm exists in bash script silently

Tags: bash, rpm

I'm trying to do a quick check to see if an rpm is installed in a bash script using an if statement. But I want to do it silently. Currently, when I run the script, and the rpm does exist, it outputs the output of rpm to the screen which I dont want.

```
if rpm -qa | grep glib; then
    do something
fi
```

Maybe there is an option to rpm that I am missing? or if I just need to change my statement?

THanks

Comment: rpm -qa is more expensive than just doing rpm -q glib. the trick is to know the package name in advance so to spend less time searching for it individually

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) You can add -q switch to grep

```
if rpm -qa | grep -q glib; then
  do something
fi
```

2) You can redirect stout and/or stderr output to /dev/null

```
if rpm -qa | grep glib  2>&1 > /dev/null; then
  do something
fi
```

Comment: The answer with rpm -q > /dev/null is a bit more elegant.  No need to bring grep into the matter.

Answer (score 18):

There is the interesting `--quiet` option available for the `rpm` command. Man page says:

```
   --quiet
          Print  as little as possible - normally only error messages will
          be displayed.
```

So probably you may like to use this one:

```
if rpm -q --quiet glib ; then 
  do something 
fi
```

This way should be faster because it doesn't have to wait a `-qa` (query all) rpm packages installed but just queries the target rpm package. Of course you have to know the correct name of the package you want to test if is installed or not.

Note: using RPM version 4.9.1.2 on fedora 15

Answer (score 8):

You need only -q option actually:

```
$ rpm -q zabbix-agent

package zabbix-agent is not installed

$ rpm -q curl

curl-7.24.0-5.25.amzn1.x86_64
```

It will look like:

```
$ if rpm -q zabbix-agent > /dev/null; then echo "Package zabbix-agent is already installed."; fi

Package zabbix-agent is already installed.
```

Comment: Let me explain it. There is no need in rpm -aq and grep if you can do only rpm -q PACKAGE_NAME. So rpm will do grep for you.

Comment: This is the more elegant answer than the accepted one.  The return value from rpm -q is all you need.  Funnily, -qa doesn't return the same return codes, so you need to redirect stdout to /dev/null and stick with -q.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
[ -z "$(rpm -qa|grep glib)" ] && echo none || echo present
```

...or, if you prefer:

```
if [ $(rpm -qa|grep -c glib) -gt 0 ]; then
    echo present
else
    echo none
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test if the command returns a string, the command substitution will capture the output:

```
[[ "$(rpm -qa | grep glib)" ]] && do something
```

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt(CurlHandle $handle, int $option, mixed $value): bool

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

RPM, for whatever reason, doesn't provide a method that accepts a list of package names, and returns a list of those already installed (or the opposite, where it prints any which aren't already installed). Because it likes to print warnings for names which don't match, you can't take the output and feed it directly into another command, without using something like grep to filter the output.

While using `grep` will work, and is perfectly fine for interactive use cases, its a fragile strategy. And should  should be avoided in an automatation/scripted situation. Thtat's because the string you might be looking for, like "is not installed" could be changed by the developers in a future release, or if someone tries to run your script/logic on a system configured to use a different language.

This is a better strategy:

```bash
#- echo "glib glib2" | tr ' ' '\n' | while read PKG ; do { rpm --quiet -q "$PKG" && echo "$PKG" ; } ; done
glib2
```

In my case, I needed a list of already installed QEMU installed, so I could replace them with rebuilt RPMs. And I didn't want to generate a lot of meaningless errors/warnings which might confuse others into thinking there was a problem. So I needed a list of the installed packages, that I could use during an install/removal transaction. The real world result looks like this:

```bash
#- echo "qemu-img qemu-kvm qemu-kvm-audio-pa qemu-kvm-block-curl qemu-kvm-block-rbd qemu-kvm-common qemu-kvm-core qemu-kvm-debugsource qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-gl qemu-kvm-device-usb-host qemu-kvm-device-usb-redirect qemu-kvm-docs qemu-kvm-tools qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless qemu-kvm-ui-opengl qemu-pr-helper virtiofsd qemu-kvm-audio-pa-debuginfo qemu-kvm-block-curl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-block-rbd-debuginfo qemu-kvm-block-ssh-debuginfo qemu-kvm-common-debuginfo qemu-kvm-core-debuginfo qemu-kvm-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-gl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-usb-host-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-usb-redirect-debuginfo qemu-kvm-tests-debuginfo qemu-kvm-tools-debuginfo qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless-debuginfo qemu-kvm-ui-opengl-debuginfo qemu-guest-agent-debuginfo qemu-img-debuginfo qemu-pr-helper-debuginfo virtiofsd-debuginfo virtiofsd-debugsource" | tr ' ' '\n' | while read PKG ; do { rpm --quiet -q "$PKG" && echo "$PKG" ; } ; done
qemu-img
qemu-kvm
qemu-kvm-audio-pa
qemu-kvm-block-curl
qemu-kvm-block-rbd
qemu-kvm-common
qemu-kvm-core
qemu-kvm-debugsource
qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu
qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl
qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci
qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl
qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga
qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-gl
qemu-kvm-device-usb-host
qemu-kvm-device-usb-redirect
qemu-kvm-docs
qemu-kvm-tools
qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless
qemu-kvm-ui-opengl
qemu-pr-helper
virtiofsd
```

The final result for my use case looked something this (the example is using a hard-coded list of RPM file names for simplicity):

```bash
#- REMOVEPKGS=$(echo `echo "qemu-img qemu-kvm qemu-kvm-audio-pa qemu-kvm-block-curl qemu-kvm-block-rbd qemu-kvm-common qemu-kvm-core qemu-kvm-debugsource qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-gl qemu-kvm-device-usb-host qemu-kvm-device-usb-redirect qemu-kvm-docs qemu-kvm-tools qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless qemu-kvm-ui-opengl qemu-pr-helper virtiofsd qemu-kvm-audio-pa-debuginfo qemu-kvm-block-curl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-block-rbd-debuginfo qemu-kvm-block-ssh-debuginfo qemu-kvm-common-debuginfo qemu-kvm-core-debuginfo qemu-kvm-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-gl-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-usb-host-debuginfo qemu-kvm-device-usb-redirect-debuginfo qemu-kvm-tests-debuginfo qemu-kvm-tools-debuginfo qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless-debuginfo qemu-kvm-ui-opengl-debuginfo qemu-guest-agent-debuginfo qemu-img-debuginfo qemu-pr-helper-debuginfo virtiofsd-debuginfo virtiofsd-debugsource" | tr ' ' '\n' | while read PKG ; do { rpm --quiet -q "$PKG" && echo "$PKG" ; } ; done`)
#- INSTALLPKGS="edk2-aarch64-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.noarch.rpm edk2-arm-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.noarch.rpm edk2-ovmf-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.noarch.rpm edk2-tools-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm edk2-tools-doc-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.noarch.rpm edk2-tools-python-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.noarch.rpm libcacard-2.8.1-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm libcacard-devel-2.8.1-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm lzfse-1.0-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm lzfse-devel-1.0-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm lzfse-libs-1.0-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm mesa-libgbm-devel-21.3.4-2.el9.x86_64.rpm openbios-20200725-5.git7f28286.btrh9.noarch.rpm pcsc-lite-devel-1.9.4-1.el9.x86_64.rpm qemu-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-audio-alsa-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-audio-dbus-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-audio-oss-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-audio-pa-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-audio-sdl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-audio-spice-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-block-curl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-block-dmg-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-block-iscsi-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-block-rbd-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-block-ssh-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-char-baum-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-char-spice-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-common-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-qxl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-vhost-user-gpu-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-ccw-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-vga-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-display-virtio-vga-gl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-usb-host-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-usb-redirect-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-device-usb-smartcard-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-docs-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-guest-agent-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-img-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-kvm-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-kvm-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-pr-helper-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-aarch64-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-aarch64-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-alpha-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-alpha-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-arm-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-arm-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-avr-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-avr-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-cris-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-cris-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-hppa-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-hppa-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-loongarch64-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-loongarch64-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-m68k-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-m68k-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-microblaze-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-microblaze-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-mips-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-mips-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-nios2-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-nios2-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-or1k-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-or1k-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-ppc-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-ppc-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-riscv-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-riscv-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-rx-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-rx-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-s390x-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-s390x-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-sh4-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-sh4-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-sparc-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-sparc-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-tricore-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-tricore-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-x86-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-x86-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-xtensa-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-system-xtensa-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-tests-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-tools-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-curses-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-dbus-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-egl-headless-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-gtk-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-opengl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-sdl-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-spice-app-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-ui-spice-core-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-binfmt-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-aarch64-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-alpha-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-arm-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-cris-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-hexagon-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-hppa-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-loongarch64-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-m68k-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-microblaze-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-mips-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-nios2-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-or1k-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-ppc-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-riscv-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-s390x-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-sh4-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-sparc-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-x86-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-user-static-xtensa-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm qemu-virtiofsd-7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64.rpm SDL2_image-2.0.5-6.el9.remi.x86_64.rpm SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-6.el9.remi.x86_64.rpm SLOF-20210217-5.git33a7322d.btrh9.noarch.rpm spice-glib-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-glib-devel-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-gtk-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-gtk3-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-gtk3-devel-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-gtk3-vala-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-gtk-tools-0.40-1.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-server-0.15.0-5.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-server-devel-0.15.0-5.btrh9.x86_64.rpm spice-protocol-0.14.4-2.btrh9.noarch.rpm virglrenderer-0.10.1-1.20220912git19dc97a2.btrh9.x86_64.rpm virglrenderer-devel-0.10.1-1.20220912git19dc97a2.btrh9.x86_64.rpm virglrenderer-test-server-0.10.1-1.20220912git19dc97a2.btrh9.x86_64.rpm"
#- bash -c 'dnf shell --assumeyes <(printf "%s\n" "install $INSTALLPKGS" "remove $REMOVEPKGS" "run" "clean all" "exit")'
AlmaLinux 9 - AppStream                                                                3.9 MB/s | 8.6 MB     00:02
AlmaLinux 9 - BaseOS                                                                   1.5 MB/s | 4.2 MB     00:02
AlmaLinux 9 - Extras                                                                    31 kB/s |  13 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64                                         3.6 MB/s |  11 MB     00:03
=======================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch      Version                                  Repository       Size
=======================================================================================================================
Installing:
 SDL2_image                                   x86_64    2.0.5-6.el9.remi                         @commandline     82 k
 SDL2_image-devel                             x86_64    2.0.5-6.el9.remi                         @commandline     11 k
 SLOF                                         noarch    20210217-5.git33a7322d.btrh9             @commandline    218 k
 edk2-aarch64                                 noarch    20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9          @commandline    5.6 M
 edk2-arm                                     noarch    20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9          @commandline    2.8 M
 edk2-tools                                   x86_64    20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9          @commandline    405 k
 edk2-tools-doc                               noarch    20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9          @commandline     77 k
 edk2-tools-python                            noarch    20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9          @commandline    1.6 M
 libcacard                                    x86_64    3:2.8.1-3.btrh9                          @commandline     55 k
 libcacard-devel                              x86_64    3:2.8.1-3.btrh9                          @commandline     18 k
 lzfse                                        x86_64    1.0-1.btrh9                              @commandline     14 k
 lzfse-devel                                  x86_64    1.0-1.btrh9                              @commandline    8.8 k
 lzfse-libs                                   x86_64    1.0-1.btrh9                              @commandline     25 k
 mesa-libgbm-devel                            x86_64    21.3.4-2.el9                             @commandline     17 k
 openbios                                     noarch    1:20200725-5.git7f28286.btrh9            @commandline    303 k
 pcsc-lite-devel                              x86_64    1.9.4-1.el9                              @commandline     45 k
 qemu                                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     15 k
 qemu-audio-alsa                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     24 k
 qemu-audio-dbus                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     25 k
 qemu-audio-oss                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     23 k
 qemu-audio-pa                                x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     24 k
 qemu-audio-sdl                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     21 k
 qemu-audio-spice                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     20 k
 qemu-block-curl                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     26 k
 qemu-block-dmg                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     20 k
 qemu-block-iscsi                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     34 k
 qemu-block-rbd                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     30 k
 qemu-block-ssh                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     29 k
 qemu-char-baum                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     23 k
 qemu-char-spice                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     22 k
 qemu-common                                  x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    568 k
 qemu-device-display-qxl                      x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     43 k
 qemu-device-display-vhost-user-gpu           x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    236 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     37 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-ccw           x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     19 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     25 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci           x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     19 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl        x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     18 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-vga               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     20 k
 qemu-device-display-virtio-vga-gl            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     18 k
 qemu-device-usb-host                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     32 k
 qemu-device-usb-redirect                     x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     39 k
 qemu-device-usb-smartcard                    x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     27 k
 qemu-docs                                    x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    1.0 M
 qemu-guest-agent                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    307 k
 qemu-system-aarch64                          x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-aarch64-core                     x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    4.8 M
 qemu-system-alpha                            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-alpha-core                       x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    3.1 M
 qemu-system-arm                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-arm-core                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    4.4 M
 qemu-system-avr                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-avr-core                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.2 M
 qemu-system-cris                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-cris-core                        x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.2 M
 qemu-system-hppa                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-hppa-core                        x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    3.4 M
 qemu-system-loongarch64                      x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-loongarch64-core                 x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    3.2 M
 qemu-system-m68k                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-m68k-core                        x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.6 M
 qemu-system-microblaze                       x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-microblaze-core                  x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.7 M
 qemu-system-mips                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-mips-core                        x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     13 M
 qemu-system-nios2                            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-nios2-core                       x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.2 M
 qemu-system-or1k                             x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-or1k-core                        x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.2 M
 qemu-system-ppc                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-ppc-core                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    8.4 M
 qemu-system-riscv                            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-riscv-core                       x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    6.7 M
 qemu-system-rx                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-rx-core                          x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.2 M
 qemu-system-s390x                            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-s390x-core                       x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.8 M
 qemu-system-sh4                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-sh4-core                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    6.0 M
 qemu-system-sparc                            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-sparc-core                       x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    5.2 M
 qemu-system-tricore                          x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-tricore-core                     x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    2.2 M
 qemu-system-x86                              x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-x86-core                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    7.2 M
 qemu-system-xtensa                           x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     16 k
 qemu-system-xtensa-core                      x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    6.8 M
 qemu-tests                                   x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    652 k
 qemu-tools                                   x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    370 k
 qemu-ui-curses                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     28 k
 qemu-ui-dbus                                 x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     77 k
 qemu-ui-egl-headless                         x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     20 k
 qemu-ui-gtk                                  x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     43 k
 qemu-ui-opengl                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     25 k
 qemu-ui-sdl                                  x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     30 k
 qemu-ui-spice-app                            x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     21 k
 qemu-ui-spice-core                           x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     38 k
<<<SNIPPED>>>>
 spice-glib                                   x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline    360 k
 spice-glib-devel                             x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline    106 k
 spice-gtk                                    x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline     31 k
 spice-gtk-tools                              x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline     40 k
 spice-gtk3                                   x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline     65 k
 spice-gtk3-devel                             x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline     18 k
 spice-gtk3-vala                              x86_64    0.40-1.btrh9                             @commandline     14 k
 spice-protocol                               noarch    0.14.4-2.btrh9                           @commandline     30 k
 spice-server                                 x86_64    0.15.0-5.btrh9                           @commandline    385 k
 spice-server-devel                           x86_64    0.15.0-5.btrh9                           @commandline     17 k
 virglrenderer                                x86_64    0.10.1-1.20220912git19dc97a2.btrh9       @commandline    211 k
 virglrenderer-devel                          x86_64    0.10.1-1.20220912git19dc97a2.btrh9       @commandline     13 k
 virglrenderer-test-server                    x86_64    0.10.1-1.20220912git19dc97a2.btrh9       @commandline     27 k
Upgrading:
 edk2-ovmf                                    noarch    20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9          @commandline     10 M
 qemu-img                                     x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    1.8 M
 qemu-kvm                                     x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     14 k
 qemu-kvm-core                                x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline     14 k
 qemu-pr-helper                               x86_64    768:7.1.0-3.btrh9                        @commandline    327 k
Removing:
 qemu-kvm-audio-pa                            x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       28 k
 qemu-kvm-block-curl                          x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       40 k
 qemu-kvm-block-rbd                           x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       41 k
 qemu-kvm-common                              x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream      1.4 M
 qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu           x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       56 k
 qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-gl        x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       15 k
 qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci       x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       15 k
 qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-gpu-pci-gl    x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       15 k
 qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga           x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       16 k
 qemu-kvm-device-display-virtio-vga-gl        x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       15 k
 qemu-kvm-device-usb-host                     x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       54 k
 qemu-kvm-device-usb-redirect                 x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       73 k
 qemu-kvm-docs                                x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream      9.7 M
 qemu-kvm-tools                               x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream      1.1 M
 qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless                     x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       15 k
 qemu-kvm-ui-opengl                           x86_64    17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5                      @appstream       32 k
 virtiofsd                                    x86_64    1.1.0-4.el9_0                            @appstream      1.9 M

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================
Install  133 Packages
Upgrade    5 Packages
Remove    17 Packages

Total size: 171 M
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                               1/1
  Installing       : qemu-common-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64                                                        1/160
  Running scriptlet: qemu-common-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64                                                        1/160
  Installing       : qemu-ui-opengl-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64                                                     2/160
<<<<SNIPPED>>>>
  Cleanup          : qemu-kvm-17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5.x86_64                                                       139/160
  Cleanup          : qemu-kvm-core-17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5.x86_64                                                  140/160
  Erasing          : qemu-kvm-ui-egl-headless-17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5.x86_64                                       141/160
<<<<SNIPPED>>>>
Upgraded:
  edk2-ovmf-20220826gitba0e0e4c6a17-1.btrh9.noarch                qemu-img-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64
  qemu-kvm-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64                               qemu-kvm-core-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64
  qemu-pr-helper-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64
Installed:
  qemu-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64
  qemu-audio-alsa-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64
  qemu-audio-dbus-768:7.1.0-3.btrh9.x86_64
<<<SNIPPED>>>>
Removed:
  qemu-kvm-audio-pa-17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5.x86_64
  qemu-kvm-block-curl-17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5.x86_64
  qemu-kvm-block-rbd-17:6.2.0-11.el9_0.5.x86_64
<<<<SNIPPED>>>>
Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:18 ago on Wed 19 Oct 2022 08:59:40 AM UTC.
34 files removed
Leaving Shell
```

Snipped to stay within character limit.